# Markdown Regex in R

Tags: regex, r

I'm having a bit of a problem recognizing ONLY second level header items.

```
x <- c("## This","## This \n\n ### That \n\n ## This again","## The Other")
```

Basically, I need to replace such that the second level header is like this:

```
"---\n\n## This"      
"---\n\n## This \n\n ### That \n\n ---\n\n## This again"     
"---\n\n## The Other"
```

I've tried a bunch of different combinations and experiments with gsub. But I can't seem to get it to ignore the third or header > 2nd level header items.

```
gsub("## ","---\n\n## ",x )
gsub("##\\s","---\n\n## ",x)
```

Comment: Check your requested output.  Are you sure that's what you want given the input you've shown?  Shouldn't "This Again" come right after the first "This"?

Comment: Updated, thanks for reading my mind G.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find strings that begin with `"##"` or that *don't* begin with a `"#"` and are followed by `"## "` like this, using `|`

```
gsub("^## |[^#]## ", "---\n\n## ", x)

[1] "---\n\n## This"                                        
[2] "---\n\n## This \n\n ### That \n\n---\n\n## This again"
[3] "---\n\n## The Other"
```

The `^` inside of brackets means "not."  Outside of brackets, it means, "begins with"

Comment: Bah! I tried that, but I think with \\s at the end. Thanks GSee.

Comment: Actually, this captures the first occurence in an element, but ignores all subsequent occurences. I'm going to update my example.

Comment: Shouldn't `"[^#]## "` capture (and thus replace) the character that is not a `#`? I can see the output is correct, but why?

Comment: @Pharaoh, you are correct.  It was a copy/paste error.  I corrected the output (removed the space).

Answer (score 5):

Try `"(?<!#)## "`
It captures all occurences of `"## "` that are not preceded by `#`.

```
> gsub("(?<!#)## ", "---\n\n## ", x, perl=TRUE)
[1] "---\n\n## This"                                        
[2] "---\n\n## This \n\n ### That \n\n ---\n\n## This again"
[3] "---\n\n## The Other"
```

Answer (score 1):

From the question, it seems like the OP is trying to find a way to generate slide separators for Slidify (which I am the author of). All the answers above work great, when the document does not contain any code chunks with comments. I have a solution that ignores code chunks with comments, and am posting it here primarily for completion sake. The `slide_header` argument can be used to define headers that should be prepended with a separator.

````
find_code_lines <- function(doc){
  code_blocks = which(grepl("^```", doc))
  code_lines = NULL
  for (i in seq.int(1, length(code_blocks), by = 2)){
    code_lines = c(code_lines, code_blocks[i]:code_blocks[i + 1])
  }
  return(code_lines)
}

add_slide_separator <- function(deckFile, slide_header = "###"){
  doc <- readLines(deckFile)
  code_lines = find_code_lines(doc)
  pattern = paste0('^(', slide_header, ".*)")
  doc[-c(code_lines)] = gsub(pattern, '\n---\n\\1', doc[-c(code_lines)])
  writeLines(doc, con = deckFile)
}
````

I see that my code will fail to distinguish between `##` and `###` and modifying the gsub line to `gsub("^## |[^#]## ", "---\n\n## ", x)` as in the accepted answer will make it work.

Comment: Yes, you're right, this was for the google docs integration that we've been discussing wrt Slidify. The reason code chunks with comment doesn't matter to me is that all of the chunks need to be externalized for it to work in the first place. At least the way I've written it.

Comment: Got it. I confused it with some requests I have been getting to write decks without a separator, automatically breaking slides like pandoc.